# Elastic search index number of documents and scores change when recreating index from scratch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been experimenting with elasticsearch, and am stuck on understanding scoring and indexation.

I created a river/mapping/analyzer (folding, normalization, stemming) and request to benchmark on. All of this seems to work pretty well, however I observe that if I delete my index and recreate it with the exact same configuration, the scores as well as the order of the results of my request change.

Moreover, the number of documents and the size of the index change upon recreation (23.718 docs/19.7MB to 20.072/13.5MB for instance) while there is no sign of error in elasticsearch logs and the query in my river always outputs the same number of rows.

Is that possibly expected? If not, where should I look and what could be wrong?

**EDIT:**
I am using elasticsearch 1.1.1, with mysql (5.5) river using mysql-jdbc 5.1.26 and elasticsearch river-jdbc 2.2.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more detail about what version of elasticsearch you are using, river-plugin, database etc.

Comment: I edited my message, let me know if I missed something. Thanks